# Confused on c# lambda expression with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, lambda

I am trying to understand this part of code:

```
int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
Color32[] colors = mesh.colors32;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<byte, int>> hierarchyMap = colors
        .Select((color, index) => new { color, index })
        .GroupBy(c => c.color.g, c => c.index);

IEnumerable<int> leafIndexes = hierarchyMap
        .Where(x => x.Key == 255)
        .SelectMany(x=>x);

Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> faces = triangles
        .Select((vert, index) => new { vert, index })
        .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, i => i.vert)
        .Where(g=> leafIndexes.Any(leaf=>g.Contains(leaf)))
        .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>new HashSet<int>(g));
```

These code look like magic for me. It seems like "c" represents each element in colors, and type `Color32` indeed has a property called `color`. But in the last line, `triangle` is an array of type `int`, how can an `int` type have an property called `vert`? And both `int` and `Color32` don't have property `index`.

I am so confused on these expressions, I only find some simple example of Lambda expression online. After reading the examples, I am still stuck on these codes.

Comment: That code is unreadable. Putting everything in one line just because is a *very* bad idea. I suspect if you clean up the code it will be a lot easier to understand

Comment: In any case there are a lot of tutorials and explanations on Lambda and LINQ. This code is trying to be clever though, ending up being wasteful. The first `Select()` uses an overload that returns an item and its index. `GroupBy` then groups those indexes by their color values. It could simply have created a dictionary of `Color,Index` instead. `leafIndexes` though contains *only* colors whose value is `255` making the entire grouping pointless. The first two queries simply return the indexes of `Color == 255`

Comment: The final query is bad too - it tries to consume vertices in threes, but does so using the wrong operators. The indexed select and `GroupBy (i/3)` are trying to do what's essentially batching items in threes. After that, it tries to filter only those triangles whose vertices appear in the `leafIndexes` list

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, this code is too "clever" for its own good, and very, very slow due to repeated iterations.

The first two queries are redundant, as in the end, `leafIndexes` contains just the indexes of `color` 255, or rather, `0x0000FF`. `Select((item,index)=>...)` passes the item *and* its index to the lambda. Those two queries could be just :

```
var leafIndexes=colors.Select((color,idx)=>{color,idx})
                      .Where(color=>color=255)
                      .Select(pair=>pair.idx)
                      .ToList();
```

Or, using an iterator function:

```
IEnumerable<int> ColorIndexes(IEnumerable<Color32> colors,int color)
{
    int i=0;
    foreach(var c in colors)
    {
        if(c==color) yield return i;
        i++;
    }
}

... 

var leafIndexes=ColorIndexes(colors,255).ToList();
```

The final query tries to batch vertices in threes. An iterator method could also help here, but a better idea would be to use [MoreLINQ's Batch](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) operator :

```
int[] vertices= mesh.triangles;
var triangles=vertices.Batch(3);
```

After that, the query tries to find which "triangle" values are contained in the leafIndexes list. Each "triangle" is a list of numbers though. We could write:

```
var finalTriangles=triangles.Where(points=> points.Any(point=>leafIndexes.Contains(point));
```

Which tries to find if any of the triangle points is contained in the leaf indexes. Or we could use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) to see if the the two arrays have any values in common:

```
var finalTriangles=vertices.Batch(3)
                           .Where(points=> points.Intersect(leafIndexes).Any());
```

The final step in the query creates a dictionary with the matching "triangles" whose key is the "triangle" index. Again, this is a job for `Select((item,index))` :

```
int[] vertices= mesh.triangles;
var finalTriangles=vertices.Batch(3)
                           .Select((triplet,idx)=>{ triplet=triplet.ToList(),
                                                    idx})
                           .Where(pair=> pair.triplet.Intersect(leafIndexes).Any())
                           .ToDictionary(pair=>pair.idx,
                                         pair=>pair.triplet);
```

The code uses `ToList()` to execute the enumerable just once and return a List`. Without it, every time`triplet`or`leafIndexes` was used, the query would execute again.

The one thing this code *doesn't* do is put the points into a `HashSet`. This class is meant for fast, set-based, **in-place** operations. If `triplet` was a HashSet, calling `IntersectWith` would modify it and leave only the numbers found in `leafIndexes`.

Answer (score 0):

> how can an int type have an property called vert? And both int and Color32 don't have property index.

You are confusing one thing here: These are no "properties" but iteration variables.

Linq basically almost all the time is a shortcut for a

```
foreach(var color in colors)
```

for example. It is totally up to you if you call it `color` or `item` or anything else!

Honestly I didn't know but apparently the `index` you can just include when you need it. It is the index of according element within the list/IEnumerable you are using Linq on.

So in `GroupBy` you could actually again call it `color` instead of `c`.

Also in the later `vert` is no property but simply is a name for the current item .. you could also use

```
Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> faces = triangles
    .Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
```

and it would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: The question's code is trying to be too clever, but uses the wrong functions to 1) just filter some values and b) batch vertices in 3s. Even very experienced developers would have to reverse engineer what this code does to understand it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats probably a question of taste though. I didn't say it was good to use but tried to clear the misunderstanding OP has about where the names come from ;)

Comment: But you didn't really - the first two queries simply return the indexes of a specific color value in an array. The second tries to *batch* values in threes. All of this is wasteful and actually awfully slow due to repeated iterations. It took me 10 minutes of looking at this trying to understand what it does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well I didn't come to answer what exactly the code does in the end that's true. Everyone can checkout the c# docs and go through it step by step. I rather wanted to clarify the basic underlying question of where these iterator names come from. If you already took the time to decrypt the code go ahead and answer it ;) it's just that I consider that the OPs homework after understanding where the names and indices come from ^^